# Client for NFS - Windows Server 2008 R2 vs Windows Server 2003 R2 - Explorer shows disconnect

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, nfs

I am currently utilizing Client for NFS on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2003 R2 to connect to a network drive via the mount command:

mount \computerName\shareName DRIVE_LETTER:

I use the exact same command on both OS's and the connection is made successfully via DOS console I initiated the command from.  I can also see the mounts via DOS console via 'mount'

When viewing the mounts in Explorer on the Windows 2003 R2 machines, I can see the drive in the left pane, and can click on it to see it's contents in the right pane.

When viewing the mounts in Explorer on the Windows 2008 R2 machines, the NFS mounts have a red 'X' though them, but I can click on them and view the contents of the drive in the right pane.

Any ideas why Windows Server 2008 R2 is showing the drive as disconnected in Explorer even though it's mounted and available via Explorer and/or DOS?

Thank You in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's by (mis-)design:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2011/09/20/getting-red-x-sign-on-mounted-nfs-volume-from-windows-client.aspx

Answer (score 0):

2008 R2 NFS mounting appears to be seriously broken compared to 2003 R2.

Why does Microsoft always seem to break stuff that has been working perfectly for years?

The answer we found was to create short symbolic links in '/' that point to the deep paths over on the Unix machine and export those and then 2008 R2 could mount them r/w.